# Mysql query using in () doesnt's work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to find all products that are connected with category list with this query:

```
SELECT p.id, product_name, added_date 
FROM products p, products_to_categories ptc 
WHERE ptc.category_id in ("89,88,83,87,84,85,86,82") 
AND ptc.product_id=p.id and p.active="1" 
group by p.id
```

if I cut the condition `AND ptc.product_id=p.id` returns rows - wrong rows for active condition..
what is the correct way to get correct information with 1 query? - is it possible at all?
thanks

Comment: what is the `datatype` of `active` column?

Comment: active is enum('0', '1')

Comment: It's generally a bad idea using numeric strings in an ENUM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't quote the list of category IDs:

```
SELECT p.id, product_name, added_date 
FROM products p
JOIN products_to_categories ptc ON ptc.product_id=p.id
WHERE ptc.category_id IN (89, 88, 83, 87, 84, 85, 86, 82) 
AND p.active="1" 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: guys, I removed the quotes and get 1 extra row, but still not full correct results, I tryed @Barmar's query and still.. what else could be?

Comment: Please post some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: your query is OK, just my fault with copy /paste.. I accept it as answered, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try removing quoting in `IN` clause and in `p.active` if active is `int/bool`

```
$q='SELECT p.id, product_name, added_date 
FROM products p, products_to_categories ptc 
WHERE ptc.category_id in (89,88,83,87,84,85,86,82) 
AND ptc.product_id=p.id and p.active=1
group by p.id';
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont encapsulate all categories with brackets. MySQL interprets this as a single category. Encapsulate each category, e.g. "89","90","91". You can also just skip the brackets altogether as it is integers you query on.

You would encapsulate the ids if they were strings, e.g. "one","two","three".